# Can I replace _task.map with Transformations.map in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

The Code A is fom the [project](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

I think Code B is the same as Code A, right?

**Code A**

```
val task: LiveData<Task?> = _task
val completed: LiveData<Boolean> = _task.map { input: Task? ->
    input?.isCompleted ?: false
}
```

**Code B**

```
val task: LiveData<Task?> = _task
val completed =  Transformations.map(_task){input: Task? ->
    input?.isCompleted ?: false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely identical because `LiveData.map` is an extension function that provided from `Transformations.kt` file that is a part of dependency:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

This is what `map` extension function does which is absolutely identical to Code B:

```
inline fun <X, Y> LiveData<X>.map(crossinline transform: (X) -> Y): LiveData<Y> =
        Transformations.map(this) { transform(it) }
```